# Exception when calling grails run-script: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication'

Tags: grails, run-script

After making changes in my grails application, if I try to call 'run-script' I get the following exception:

```
Error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication'
...
```

The extended exception will vary, depending on what changes you've made to the application.
This is occurring on grails version 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that 'run-script' (at least in version 2.3.1 of Grails) does not run 'compile' before it tries to run!

So, the solution is:

grails compile
grails run-script myScript.groovy